# Receiving console output

Tags: c++, command-line

Is there a way to execute a program and receive the console output in c++ instead of displaying the console window? I am trying to do a command line call but provide a GUI instead of the console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on most systems using `popen` (or on some compilers `_popen`). If that isn't versatile enough for your purposes, you'll probably have to do something platform specific (e.g., `fork` on a POSIX-like system, or `CreateProcess` on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can write `stdout` to a file instead, and display the file in your GUI.  One method for doing that is [`freopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/).

```
int main ()
{
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);
  printf ("This sentence is redirected to a file.");
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

This redirects `stdout` to `myfile.txt`.